app:mergeExtDexDebug FAILED Due to the lifecycle-livedata-core-2.8.3-runtime.jar missing
I was just trying to update my project from targetSDK version 33 to to 34. For that I need to update some lifecyle apis as well. Prevously I was using these versions

    //LifeCycle
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.2.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0'


Which I updated with

    //LifeCycle
    def lifecycle_version = "2.8.3"
    def arch_version = "2.2.0"

    // ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    // LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    // Lifecycles only (without ViewModel or LiveData)
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    // Saved state module for ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:$lifecycle_version"
    // Annotation processor
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"


But now its showing error which I'm not understanding.
Error
*
Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug FAILED
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"java.lang.NullPointerException","sources":[{"file":"/Users/apple/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/826f48ce73a7e66fbb6d1694a1db726c/transformed/lifecycle-livedata-core-2.8.3-runtime.jar"}],"tool":"D8"}
*

What I already tried:

Clean project -> rebuild project  // not working
Invalidate cache with all checkboxes enabled () -> invalide and restart  // not working

Please help me if anyone faced this issue or have any idea about. Thnks

I had the same issue but after update AGP from the Upgrade Assistant to gradle 8.5.1, the problem has been solved

two methods:

update the project to use AGP 8.4.0 or a later version. ref

downgrade lifecycle_version to 2.7.0


